# tcolorbox breakable through pages

Tags: tcolorbox, border, colorbox

I've tried to realize a breakable tcolorbox like this:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[2][]{
  blanker,
  %leftupper=4cm,
  after skip=8mm,%   enlarge distance to the next box
  title=#2,
  breakable,
  fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
  coltitle=cyan,
  %fontupper=\sffamily,%
  %#1
  overlay={%
      \ifcase\tcbsegmentstate
        % 0 = Box contains only an upper part
      \or%
        % 1 = Box contains an upper and a lower part
        %\path[draw=red] (segmentation.west)--(frame.south east);
      \else%
        % 2 = Box contains only a lower part
        %\path[draw=red] (frame.north west)--(frame.south east);
      \fi%
    }
    #1

\begin{document}

Previous stuff...

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
\begin{cvbox}{Esempio:} 

 long stuff...

\end{cvbox}
\end{tcolorbox}
```

The result is shown in picture[image: Result]

Is there any ways to make tcolorbox (the grey rectangle) start from page 25 (just below previous stuff) and then continue in the next page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please extend your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Answer (score 3):

Well, the code you provided was incomplete, so I had to adapt it to show the `breakable tcolorbox`. Your code contained a few peculiarities:

1. Why define a new `tcolorbox` environment when you subsequently place it in a general `tcolorbox` environment?
2. Why use the `blanker` option as that removes the frame and fill colour of the environment (unless that is exactly what you want - then why use a `tcolorbox` environment)?
3. What is the use of the second option in your `cvbox` definition? I changed that to [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15u2L.jpg) as only the `title` was given as option.

The code that produces your breakable box is:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skins,breakable]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{cvbox}[1][]{
    enhanced,
%   blanker, % <- removed as it suppresses box color and frame
    %leftupper=4cm,
    after skip=8mm,%   enlarge distance to the next box
    title=#1,
    breakable = true,
    fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
    coltitle=cyan,
    colbacktitle=gray!10,   % <- defines background color in title
    titlerule= 0pt,         % <- sets rule underneath title 
    %fontupper=\sffamily,%
    %#1
    overlay={%
        \ifcase\tcbsegmentstate
        % 0 = Box contains only an upper part
        \or%
        % 1 = Box contains an upper and a lower part
        %\path[draw=red] (segmentation.west)--(frame.south east);
        \else%
        % 2 = Box contains only a lower part
        %\path[draw=red] (frame.north west)--(frame.south east);
        \fi%
    }
    colback = gray,         % <- defines background color in box
    colframe = black!75     % <- defines color of frame
    }
    
\begin{document}
        
        \section{Previous stuff...}
        \lipsum[2-4]

        % removed the tcolorbox environment
            \begin{cvbox}[Esempio:]
                long stuff...
                \lipsum[5-8]
            \end{cvbox}

\end{document}
```

The result of the code above:

[image: tcolorbox breakable]

Comment: Thanks a lot! :]

Comment: You're welcome. I assume it does what you wanted the code to do?

Comment: Answering your Q3: having `#1` as an optional argument, as in the OP, is a common idiom for passing options to the underlying `tcolorbox` environment. For example `\begin{cvbox}[colback=red]{My title}...\end{cvbox}` would change the background colour of the title.